# Why is mongoid throwing undefined method `field' on my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have the following:

```
class Email
  include ::Mongoid::Timestamps
  include ::Mongoid::Document

  field :email_address, :type => String
  field :user_id, :type => Integer
  field :campaign, :type => String
  field :stream, :type => String
  field :component, :type => String
  embeds_many :actions
end
```

And rails is complaining it can't find the field method definition.
Does anyone one know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must include `Mongoid::Timestamps` after `Mongoid::Document`.